# How to disable a GPIO pin?

Tags: gpio

How can I disable a GPIO pin or set it to off whenever I execute a method in Python?

Comment: What do you mean by disable, are you writing or reading from the pin?

Comment: Use a wire cutter

Comment: Basically i created a stopwatch GUI using push buttons to control it. Becasuse i am using push buttons, i need to connect the start/stop/reset push button onto the gpio pin. Therefore what i want is that whenever i start the stopwatch , i want to off the pin for the reset button so that i cant press on it.

Comment: Why not just ignore the reset gpio if the stopwatch is running?

Comment: Or can we disable a method in the stopwatch class?

Comment: Kind of.  You want to set some kind of *state variable* such that when you don't want the reset button to work, it won't work.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378  When a program is busy doing something and some GUI controls are invalid for that time, it does not disable the mouse, but if you click the mouse pointer on those controls, nothing will happen.   That's what **state** is about.   There's more than one state, and if something cannot happen in all of them, you need to check what the state currently is first before you allow it.

Comment: @WernerKvalemVesterås that won't disable the pin, just make it shorter. You should know that.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo echo 11 > /sys/class/gpio/unexport
```

To disable GPIO pin 11.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that whatever you want will be handled by one of the software libraries mentioned at http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#GPIO_Code_examples